# Submitting a video or image to Facebook using blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

Tags: facebook-graph-api, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

I have racked my brains all day today trying to get this post to work. Basically I am using the blueimp JQuery-File-Upload code and I have a page with the styled input button that selects a file from the file system - an image or a video.

```
<span class="button fileinput-button">
<i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden = "true"></i>
Add Photo or Video
<!-- The file input field used as target for the file upload widget -->
<input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" />
</span>
```

I also coded into the page a form with data that is needed for the Facebook post of the image or video.

```
 <form id = "fb-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" name="fileinfo">
<!---->
<input type="hidden" name="access_token" value="<AN ACCESS TOKEN>">
<input type="hidden" name="title" value="My fabulous title" />
<input type="hidden" name="description" value="I made this movie with my own hands" />
<input type="hidden" name="name" value="My Challenge Movie" />
<input type="hidden" name="scope" value="publish_stream" />
<input type="hidden" name="app_id" value="<APP_ID>" />
<input type="hidden" name="debug" value="all" />
</form>
```

My javascript that I have customised is shown here in a fragment

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
url: url,
acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(mp3|ogg|mp4|mov|flv|gif|jpe?g|png)$/i,
dataType          : 'json',
autoUpload        : false,
singleFileUploads : true,
multipart         : true,
type             : 'POST',
disableImageResize: /Android(?!.*Chrome)|Opera/
.test(window.navigator.userAgent),
previewMaxWidth: 425,
previewMaxHeight: 600

}).on('fileuploadadd', function (e, data) {

$("#files").empty(); // to remove the canvas when a new pic is selected
$('progress').attr('value', 0);
$scope.$apply(function (response) {
$scope.image_chosen = true;
});

if(data.originalFiles[0]) {
if(data.originalFiles[0]) {
$('#fileupload').fileupload(
'option',
{
url: 'https://graph-video.facebook.com/v2.8/140954354354343/videos',
formData: $('#fb-form').serializeArray()
}
);
}
}

data.context = $('<div/>').appendTo('#files');
data.context.addClass('fix-position');

var file = data.files[0], index = 0;

var node = $('<p/>').append(uploadButton.clone(true).data(data));
node.appendTo(data.context);

})
```

Basically I am getting for images a :

```
{
"error": {
  "message": "An access token is required to request this resource.",
  "type": "OAuthException",
  "code": 104,
  "fbtrace_id": "GdH43Db1ziy"
```

}
   }

and for videos:

```
{
"error": {
    "message": "There was a problem uploading your video file. Please    try again.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 381,
    "error_subcode": 1363021,
    "is_transient": false,
    "error_user_title": "Video Upload Problem",
    "error_user_msg": "There was a problem uploading your video. Please   try again.",
    "fbtrace_id": "EnIrs+2K2uN"
},
"__debug__": {}
}
```

But the Access Token has been validated through the API explorer...

I have tried doing the upload using just HTML form elements and submitting from the page without JS and it works - so I am kind of thinking it is something to do with the JS XHR request...

Does anyone have any experience or ideas?

Comment: Have it post to a script of your own first, and in that log what POST data you receive - and then compare what’s the difference between the data the normal form sends, and your AJAX request.

Comment: Thanks.. I solved the problem but thanks for your time...